# <pre> tag adds gap above itself?

Tags: html, css, pre

I have the following HTML:

```
<h2>Embed Code</h2>
<pre>
  <code>
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
  var something = 'else';
&lt;/script&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

And the following CSS:

```
h2 {
  background:#1e7ca2;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}
pre {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
code {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: block;
  background: #1d1f20;
  color: #839496;
  font-size: .85em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

But there's a gap between the `h2` and the `pre` element that I can't seem to get rid of.

You can see the problem in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/k5V8U/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

What ever is inside `<pre>` preserves the whitespace as well..

If you remove the whitespace between `<pre>` and `<code>` like this

```
<pre><code>
```

and

```
</code></pre>
```

it gets fixed..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/k5V8U/1/

Comment: wtf is this issue. thanks a ton!

Answer (score 6):

This is due to the fact that `<pre>` preserves white space. You have empty line breaks at both the beginning and end of your `<pre>` tag. Change it to the following:

```
<h2>Embed Code</h2>
<pre><code>
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
  var something = 'else';
&lt;/script&gt;
  </code></pre>
```

You may also need to remove the line breaks at the beginning and end of your `<code>` tag:

```
<h2>Embed Code</h2>
<pre><code>&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
  var something = 'else';
&lt;/script&gt;</code></pre>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You've created this gap yourself. The `background-color` you specified is a property of `<code>`. By using newlines inside of your `<pre>` element your actually creating a new line as `<pre>` preserves white space. You may want to use

```
<h2>Embed Code</h2>
<pre><code>
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
  var something = 'else';
&lt;/script&gt;</code></pre>
```

If you wish to keep the "margin" but fill it with the color of `<code>` use

```
<h2>Embed Code</h2>
<pre><code>
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
  var something = 'else';
&lt;/script&gt;
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you need to put `<code>` element on same line as the content inside it because `<pre>` consider it start of content. There is also simple JavaScript based solution which I posted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23001060/207661 and negative margin based solution which is also in same thread.